# Reading multiple lines of strings from a file and storing it in string array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

I have a class called StringList consisting of a constructor and a de-structor. What I am shooting for is for the ability of my program to retain its strings in the array even after it is not running. The way i want to do this is to have my constructor function read strings from a file and store them into my string array (str[]). My de-structor will save my current strings into my file. I am having trouble reading and storing from the file when memory is created. I want each word to be one element in the array.
For example, in the file that is being read from, the strings are stored as such:

```
HELLO
MOM
DAD
FOUR
YELLOW
```

I want each word to be a slot. In other words. str[0] = HELLO, str[1]= MOM, str[2]=DAD and such.

Here is my constructor function:

```
StringList::StringList()
{
    numberOfStrings=0;
    str = new string[1000000];

ifstream myfile ("Read.txt");
 if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            getline(myfile,str[i]);
            numberOfString++;


        }

        myfile.close();
    }


}
```

Problem here is the for (int i=0; i<100000;i++) line
What this did is continue to fill each blank space into the element until it reached 100000.
Same if i put i<20, it would read all the contents and add blanks to fill to 20. Is there anyway to fill up to the amount of actual strings in the txt. file?

Comment: You can start by getting rid of `new` and `delete` and just using a vector to store them, resizing automatically as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NumberOfStrings++` is outside of your for loop when you read (i.e. it only gets incremented once). Also please consider using `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a dynamic array.

Here's a version of your code using std::vector instead of an array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class StringList
{
public:
    StringList(): str(1000000), numberOfStrings(0)
    {
        std::ifstream myfile ("Read.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
            {
                getline(myfile, str[i]);
                numberOfStrings++;
            }

            myfile.close();
        }
    }

    StringList::~StringList()
    {
        std::ofstream os("Read.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i <numberOfStrings; i++) 
        {
            os << str[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> str;
    int numberOfStrings;
};
```

As you can see the changes are rather minimal.

Comment: @Borgleader Im sorry but this does not work for my program. The purpose of my program revolves around a string array that holds 1000000 strings. It has multiple functions already implemented that use this str[] and i dont want to rewrite all of them to accommodate the vector<string>. Is there anyway to do it using my way. Sorry for not mentioning this is my original post

Comment: Operator[] is available on vectors. You can also make it 100000 items long during construction.

Comment: @dreamlax you're quite right. brainfart on my part. Thanks for pointing it out (I've edited my answer).

Comment: @WestonBuckeye: `vector<string>` works almost the same as `string[]`, you can still access elements with `vec[1]` or `vec[10000]`, but you get additional benefits when using `vector` over a dynamic array. Vectors can resize automatically, and memory management is handled for you.

Comment: This changes the complete format of my entire code and all rest of my 15 functions. This does not work for me.

Comment: Well you can keep using the array, your question was why is there only one string being read/written, well that was because numberOfStrings was incremented outside of the loop. That was answered and fixed. Using vector is a *strongly* suggested improvement.

Comment: @Borgleader I know right. Complete lack of effort to do anything except copy & paste. Asinine.

Comment: @Captain Oblivious I fixed that issue of the numberOfStrings. There is a problem with your assumptions. I know it is strongly recommended i agree. But that is not the issue here. This program's purpose is to learn ways to use a string array. Not a vector. I cannot use a vector. I've written piles of code so the "copy & paste" felt unnecessary

Comment: @WestonBuckeye: the good folks here are not mind readers. It is almost always assumed that you wouldn't be limited in such a way. Just look at questions where people are, seemingly stupidly by many here, implementing their own lists and such. If you're limited by certain headers or language features be sure to explain it in your post. Otherwise, in order to *fully* help you, you'll often get suggestions that may be un-helpful/usable.

Comment: @C.Lang  I edited my post a while back to limit to a certain question. If it cant be answer its fine. Im sure ill come up with something another day

Answer (score 1):

The `numberOfStrings` variable is only updated once after the `for` loop has finished. You can also simplify this without the need to specify a large number of lines to read by checking the return value of `getline` for failure. If you try to read past the end of file is `getline` will return false.

```
numberOfStrings = 0;
str = new std::string[1000000];
std::ifstream myfile("Read.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    while(getline(myfile, str[numberOfStrings]))
        numberOfStrings++;
    myfile.close();
}
```

You can simplify this even further by using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). To expand on the example provided in your answer `StringList` might look something like below.

> StringList.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class StringList
{
public:
    StringList();
    void PrintWords();
private:
    size_t numberOfLines;
    std::vector<std::string> str;
};
```

> StringList.cpp to read in single line into each string

```
#include "StringList.h"
#include <fstream>

StringList::StringList()
{
    std::ifstream myfile("Read.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while(getline(myfile, line))
        {
            lines_.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    numberOfLines = str.size();
}
```

> StringList.cpp to read in single word into each string using `std::istream_itertor` and `std::copy`

```
#include "StringList.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <algorithm> // std::copy
#include <iterator>  // istream_iterator

StringList::StringList()
{
    std::ifstream myfile("Read.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::copy(
            istream_iterator<string>(myfile),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            back_inserter(str));
    }
    numberOfLines = str.size();
}
```

> Some other function to print the words

```
StringList::PrintWords()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numberOfLines; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

<sub>I also recommend avoiding using `using namespace std` in your code. It pulls everything from `std` into the current scope (typically the global namespace) and can cause conflicts with identifiers.</sub>

Comment: Im sorry but i am a beginner to programming. Could you show me how to propery write that in my constructor function? Do i need to add any libraries for this to work?

Comment: I'll add an example while you review documentation I've linked to in my current answer ;)

Comment: What documentation? I just need this to read from the file and store each word into a slot in the string array. Where do i insert what you showed me

Comment: Oblivious Im sorry but this does not work for my program. The purpose of my program revolves around a string array that holds 1000000 strings. It has multiple functions already implemented that use this str[] and i dont want to rewrite all of them to accommodate the vector<string>. Is there anyway to do it using my way

Comment: @WestonBuckeye: No offense, but you are likely in the mess you are in now because you *aren't* using `std::vector`.

Comment: Change `lines_` to `str` and it works in the same way. `for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) { std::cout << str[i] << std::endl; }`. Either way you have examples for both.

Comment: Its not a mess. My function just only reads the first word. It is the only part of this program i dont know the coding for. @dreamlax

Comment: Yes, I removed that example because I didn't feel like expanding on how to use it to read an entire line since it was doubtful you would bother using it. You have two examples using `getline` and either an array of strings or a vector. both work.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thank you for your help! I was able to make it run with my other functions

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach to reading the data (this doesn't quite work the same as the other answers, but as long as your wordlist doesn't contain words with whitespace, it should work fine).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::fstream myFile("read.txt");
    if (myFile.is_open())
    {
        std::istream_iterator<std::string> iter(myFile), end;
        std::vector<std::string> str(iter, end);

        // print contents
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
            std::cout << i << ": " << str[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

References:

1. [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)
2. [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

You can continue to averse `std::vector` all you want, but for a scenario like this, it is the best tool for the job.

Comment: this program uses an advancedcommandLine Interface. I dont have an int main neither do i want to print its contents.

Comment: I already suggested that but removed it since the OP is reading in an entire line at a time. Even includes the use of `std::copy` to deal with the vector being member variable ;) And don't even think about including an example of anything other than modifications to `StringList`

Comment: @WestonBuckeye: The point of this answer was to illustrate how to read the contents of the file using a complete, compilable program. There are only four lines of code here that are actually doing anything relevant.